# Strengths and weaknesses of the XML data representation compared with the relational model

Tags: xml, database, relational-database

Hi i am preparing for an exam and i am stuck with this

What are the strengths and weaknesses of the XML data representation compared with the relational model?

Perhaps that is allows a hierarchical structure to be easily represented.

That it is more humanly readable

A mind boggling number of fields and tables required, almost all are optional. For example, not all novels have a villain, but a villain attribute or tag would be easy enough to add to an xml document.

Comment: Comparing apples and oranges. XML and relational DB don't cover the same needs. They are complementary in many ways. All modern DBs allow to store data as XML and query the content through xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML strenghs are:
Heirarchical structure
Readable format
Open source parsers and viewers
Easy representation of data without a structure of rows

Relational tables strength:
SQL - sofisticated querying, to which XML is non comperable.

Answer (score 0):

Relational structure is optimized for database storage and query; XML model is optimized for data interchange.

Relational model is optimized for structured data; XML model is optimized for text.